# npm ERR! Failed at the xxx@1.0.0 build script

Tags: npm

When I run the `npm run build --verbose`, I get bellow error:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The traceback is bellow, there says Unexpected token punc, I do not understand it:

```
ERROR in static/js/vendor.4776fef98deb2b7313a7.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token punc «:», expected punc «,» [./node_modules/debug/src/browser.js:168,0][static/js/vendor.4776fef98deb2b7313a7.js:55100,55]

  Build failed with errors.

npm verb lifecycle aili@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
npm verb lifecycle aili@1.0.0~build: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/ldl/repo/vue_user_site/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/home/ldl/.local/bin:/home/ldl/bin
npm verb lifecycle aili@1.0.0~build: CWD: /home/ldl/repo/vue_user_site
npm info lifecycle aili@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
npm verb stack Error: aili@1.0.0 build: `node build/build.js`
npm verb stack Exit status 1
npm verb stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:285:16)
npm verb stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
npm verb stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
npm verb stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
npm verb stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
npm verb stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
npm verb stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
npm verb pkgid qiyun@1.0.0
npm verb cwd /home/ldl/repo/vue_user_site
npm verb Linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
npm verb argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build" "--verbose"
npm verb node v8.11.1
npm verb npm  v5.6.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! qiyun@1.0.0 build: `node build/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the aili@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ldl/.npm/_logs/2018-05-11T02_00_29_973Z-debug.log
```

I also tried use `npm run-script build`, but also get this error.

My project is `Vue.js` project.

---

The `build/build.js` code is bellow, I don't know whether is caused by the code, I don't think is caused by this:

```
'use strict';
require('./check-versions')();

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

const ora = require('ora');
const rm = require('rimraf');
const path = require('path');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const config = require('../config');
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.prod.conf');

const spinner = ora('building for production...');
spinner.start();

rm(path.join(config.build.assetsRoot, config.build.assetsSubDirectory), err => {
  if (err) throw err;
  webpack(webpackConfig, (err, stats) => {
    spinner.stop();
    if (err) throw err;
    process.stdout.write(stats.toString({
      colors: true,
      modules: false,
      children: false, // If you are using ts-loader, setting this to true will make TypeScript errors show up during build.
      chunks: false,
      chunkModules: false
    }) + '\n\n');

    if (stats.hasErrors()) {
      console.log(chalk.red('  Build failed with errors.\n'));
      process.exit(1);
    }

    console.log(chalk.cyan('  Build complete.\n'));
    console.log(chalk.yellow(
      '  Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.\n' +
      '  Opening index.html over file:// won\'t work.\n'
    ));
  })
});
```

From the upper traback error info, I just think this maybe need for checkout the issue.

Comment: did you check the logs under `/home/ldl/.npm/_logs/2018-05-11T02_00_29_973Z-debug.log`? They might tell you the root cause. By the looks of it, it can be a permission issue. Could you show us what the `build` script does in your `package.json`?

Answer (score 1):

you may use 
***vue-particles***, right?

Open :

> webpack.base.conf.js

Add this object to rules array

```
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test'), resolve('node_modules/vue-particles')]
  }
```